# How do you track exit links with Omniture on Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, analytics, adobe-analytics

In Omniture, there is a best practice of tracking exit links by first issuing the tracking call with `s.tl(this, "e", "Link Name")`, and then using `setTimeout()` to actually open the link.

On Mobile Safari, opening the link with setTimeout fails because the action didn't come directly from a user interaction. The only way to open the link is to sacrifice the timeout, reducing the likeliness that the tracking call will actually go through.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I've done this, but if memory serves s.tl() actually has it's own setTimeout function set at 500 milliseconds so you may not need your own.

I think you can also do it with a boolean:

```
s.tl(true, "e", "Link Name");
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hmm, as far as I can tell, with both `true` and `this` as parameters, Omniture's code never actually calls setTimeout. I replaced the window object's setTimeout to verify this.

Comment: setting the first parameter to 'this' uses a 500ms delay before moving on to the next page. Using 'true' disables it. You can go here for additional information:

http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/whitepapers/link_tracking/index.html

Answer (score 0):

exit link are tracked automatically in the s_code.js file as long as they are  tag with href attribute.

If they are not  tag you should use the s.tl(this , "e" , "PAGE TO BE LOADED") function.
As said by Mike this function has a built in timeout setted to 500 millisecond.

Kind regards,
Claudio.